# Are there brackets/braces like this?

Tags: fastener, brackets

Are there brackets/braces like this -- right angle, typically would be used in corners?

[image]

The base turned inside-out, in comparison to this type of bracket:

[image]

Or maybe perhaps I could take larger piece of metal part & saw it to get this elusive bracket?

Comment: There are all kinds of things available. Key questions: (a) approximate size, (b) what are you trying to connect/brace?

Comment: Does it have to be one piece ?  Two L brackets might achieve your end goal.  Could you describe more about the usage, so we can avoid a XY answer ?

Comment: It's pretty well imperative that you state whet it's for. It could be as small as 40mm, as big as 150mm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are "outside corner" brackets, for instance

[image]

Simpson Strong-Tie RTA 16-Gauge ZMAX Galvanized Rigid Tie Angle for 2x Joist/Post
Model # RTA2Z|Store SKU # 1000170525, from homedepot.com

And "Fence Post Base", which you could cut to modify

[image]

Or closer, as a half-post base:

[image]

Image https://riverdrivedesigns.com/product/6-x-6-post-brackets/

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want a metal bracket, not injection molded plastic.

The trouble with the bracket shape you've given is that it requires welding to fabricate. It can't be created simply by shearing and folding flat sheet material. (One might argue that it could be stamped or drawn, but like welding, those operations cost more than a simple shear+bend.)

If you're willing to compromise a bit, you'll find several possibilities that are close to what you're after in the catalogs of the wood construction connector suppliers, eg Simpson.

[image: Simpson post base]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems I misunderstood your post with my previous reply.

Since you were not able to find the bracket you are looking for as I am certain you did your own research so I won't provide what you already know to be out there.

So I will leave you with this.

JB weld to the rescue.

I assume you want a nice solid bracket and not what you find in a lumber isle.

You can simply take a square solid metal  with the thickness you like, steel or aluminum,  say 1/8" thick, 12 X 12 inch square.

Simply cut its 4 corners to make your base and then cut 8 straight pieces to make the inside component.  So that way you won't have to bend them nor do you need to.  And it would look nicer too.

Simply use JB weld to join everything.

It will be a satisfying experience.

Hope this helps.

Take care.

Here is a 12 inch square aluminum 1/8 inch thick.  It will be perfect.

[image: 12 inch aluminum stock 1/8"thick]

Comment: Does the picture of a square piece of metal really add anything meaningful?